# Connecting Twitter Streaming API to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, streaming

I am making a React/Node.js app that will display real time tweets based on a certain filter and have figured out that I need to use Twitter's streaming API. Unfortunately after some research, I can see that Twitter's APIs do not allow CORS so I can only call Twitter's API from my node.js server.

I've set up my server to receive the stream from twitter and everything works but now I need to send this data to the client in real time as it comes in. Being new to using streams, I'm not sure what the best way is to keep the client updated every time the stream on my server gets new data/tweets.

I have a few vague ideas for how to handle this including maybe learning to use web sockets or server sent events but I have never used either of these tools so it's hard for me to determine if thats the right direction to go.

If anyone has any advice for how to handle this situation I'd really appreciate it.

My server side code is as follows...

```js
// Node.js Server

const Twitter = require('twitter'); // Twitter for Node.js library

//initializing Twitter client
var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: 'my key',
  consumer_secret: 'my secret',
  access_token_key: 'token key',
  access_token_secret: 'token secret'
});

//accesses Twitter's statuses/filter streaming endpoint + parameters
var twitterStream = client.stream('statuses/filter', {
  track: 'rangers',
  language: 'en'
});

twitterStream.on('data', function(event) {
  // when the Twitter stream has new data how do I keep the client updated with it?
  console.log(event.text);
});

twitterStream.on('error', function(error) {
  throw error;
});
```

Comment: I'd definitely suggest websockets as a possible solution here. The Account Activity API sample uses server-side Node.js code to accept webhook callbacks, and then itself uses websockets to update a connected web client. This could deliver what you are after. https://github.com/twitterdev/account-activity-dashboard

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I ended up using Socket.io since the account activity endpoint didn't offer the data I was looking for. It worked like a charm.